# Removing Items Stored in Local Memory With Checked Boxes Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, local-storage

I have items being stored in an array then the array stored in local memory.

i am printing out the items to the screen for the users to see with check boxes attached to each item.

I allow the user to clear all of the items in the localStorage like this,

```
$('#clear').click( function() {
window.localStorage.clear();
location.reload();
return false;
});
```

I want to allow the user to clear any one check boxed item they want. How can I implement a function to remove the selected check boxed item from the array.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
localArray = [];

loadKeyWords();

function loadKeyWords() {
    $('#keyWords').html('');
    localArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('keyWords'));
    for(var i = 0; i < localArray.length; i++) {
      $('#keyWords').prepend('<li><input id="check" name="check" type="checkbox">'+localArray[i]+'</li>'); 
        }
    }

$('#add').click( function() {
   var Description = $('#description').val();
  if($("#description").val() === '') {
    $('#alert').html("<strong>Warning!</strong> You left the to-do empty");
    $('#alert').fadeIn().delay(1000).fadeOut();
    return false;
   }
   $('#form')[0].reset();
   var keyWords = $('#keyWords').html();
   localArray.push(Description);
   localStorage.setItem('keyWords', JSON.stringify(localArray));
   loadKeyWords();
   return false;
});

if(localStorage.getItem('keyWords')) {
$('#keyWords').JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('keyWords'));
}

$('#clear').click( function() {
window.localStorage.clear();
location.reload();
return false;
});

$('#clearChecked').click( function() {
    if ($(this).is(':unchecked')) {
      localArray.push($(this).val());
    }
    else {
      if ((index = localArray.indexOf($(this).val())) !== -1) {
                    localArray.splice(index, 1);
    }
       $('#form')[0].reset();
   var keyWords = $('#keyWords').html();
   localArray.push(Description);
   localStorage.setItem('keyWords', JSON.stringify(localArray));
   loadKeyWords();
   window.location.reload();
   return false;
          }
    });
}); // End of document ready function
```

My HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Wuno Zensorship</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="icon48.png">

 <section>
<form id="form" action="#" method="POST">
<input id="description" name="description" type="text" />
<input id="add" type="submit" value="Add" />
<button id="clearChecked">Clear Checked Items</button>
<button id="clear">Clear All</button>
</form>
<div id="alert"></div>
<ul id="keyWords"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How are you storing values in `localStorage`? Is it a JSON dump or individual values?

Comment: localStorage.setItem('keyWords', JSON.stringify(localArray));
I updated with all of my code from the js file

Comment: @NichoDiaz in that case parse localStorage value. delete value of specific checkbox and set new value in localStorage.

Comment: I am pretty new to this, side of things,  Would you mind showing me exactly how you would do that. It took me three days to get together what I just posted lol

Comment: `Description` is not declared inside `$('#clearChecked').click` handler

Comment: Nice catch, But still the function is not working. I am sure I am not writing it correctly. I am just basing my function off of examples of peoples of the internet. Would one of you mind explaining how to remove the values from my array. I can update local storage no problem I just need to get the value out of the array first.

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate over the `ul` looking for the `li` elements whose`checkbox` are checked, then remove them from `localArray`. Try this:

```
$('#clearChecked').click( function() {
    $('#keyWords > li > input:checked').each(function(){
      var desc = $(this).parent().text();
      var index = localArray.indexOf(desc);
      localArray.splice(index, 1);
    });
    ...
});
```